# How display SUM() in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this function which displays the top 30 users. It must display the viewS column for each user. I'm trying to print it out with `echo`, but nothing comes out.

```
function Wo_FeaturedUsers($limit = '', $type = '')
{
    global $wo, $sqlConnect;
    if ($wo['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }
    $data = array();
    $logged_user_id = $wo['user']['user_id'];
    $query_one = " SELECT `user_id`  FROM `Wo_Posts` WHERE  `user_id` =`user_id`";
    $sql = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, $query_one);
    $mysql_count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if ($mysql_count > 27) {
        $query_one = " SELECT `user_id`, SUM(views)
FROM `Wo_Posts`
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 90
DAY ) AND page_id = 0 GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY  SUM(`views`) DESC LIMIT 30
";
        $sql = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, $query_one);
        while ($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $data[] = Wo_UserData($fetched_data['user_id']);
        } 
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $sum = $row["SUM(views)"];
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `AS` keyword when doing SQL query

```
SELECT `user_id`, SUM(views) AS my_sum FROM `Wo_Posts`
....
ORDER BY my_sum DESC
```

and then you will be able to access it through PHP easily in `my_sum` key of array

```
$sum = $row["my_sum"];
```

---

But if you check your code, you are doing `my_sum` retrieve from DB only if first quers has more than 27 entries. If it does not have more than 27, then you want to check for your SUM value, which is not in first query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $sum = $row["SUM(views)"];
}
```

This code is on wrong position. While loop should be inside `if` statement otherwise your SUM is not retrieved from DB because you are reading SUM from DB in second query.

Comment: I was trying to use AS
but no result

Comment: @РоманРоманович I updated answer. What is in fact 27 number?

Comment: I do not know php so I applied for help please help

Comment: $sql = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, $query_one);
   {
        $query_one = " SELECT `user_id`, SUM(views) AS my_sum
FROM `Wo_Posts`
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 90
DAY ) AND page_id = 0 GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY  my_sum DESC LIMIT 30
";
        $sql = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, $query_one);
        while ($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$sum = $row["my_sum"];

            $data[] = Wo_UserData($fetched_data['user_id']);
        } 
    } 
    return $data;
}